# Twitter api is giving error

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter

I am writing this program to get data from twitter of hashtags but it give me the error

```
import twitter
import json
import urllib
twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
for page in range(1,2):
    k_results=twitter_search.search(q="jonson",rpp=100,page=page)
print json.dumps(k_results, sort_keys=True, indent=1)
```

errors are

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 2, in <module>
    k_results=twitter_search.search(q="Burma",rpp=100,page=page)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter\api.py", line 173, in __call__
    return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\twitter\api.py", line 198, in _handle_response
    raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)
TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 410 for URL: search.json using parameters: (q=Burma&rpp=100&page=1)
details: ﾋ
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to use API 1.0 endpoint, http://search.twitter.com/search.format. [It returns status `410, gone`](https://dev.twitter.com/blog/planning-for-api-v1-retirement):

> When `API v1` is finally retired, all authenticated and unauthenticated requests to `API v1` will return a `HTTP 410 Gone` status. Older widgets will receive the same response. This status code signifies that all `API v1`-era resources are gone and not coming back.

Correct url for 1.1 search is https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json

I don't know whether `twitter` module you're using is updated to use API 1.1, and suggest to use [one of modules that is](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#python).

Comment: @Ahmad see update of my answer. There are more differences in api 1.1 and api 1.0 than just links, not sure whether your code can be updated to reflect 1.1 requirements. P.ex. as I recall, `rpp` paramether is obsolete.

Comment: +1 , TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 400 for URL: search.json using parameters: (q=Burma) , is this also api error ? because i used that code six months before

Comment: @Ahmad I suggest to use tweepy (but this is opinion based :), see samples here http://www.nirg.net/blog/2013/04/using-tweepy/