# What is 410 error status in Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have been trying to make an API to retweet using status id, but I got a 410 status error. I searched how to make a retweet and I found the following code, but I face the mentioned error:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    require 'tmhOAuth.php';

    $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array( 
                                    'consumer_key'    => $consumerKey,
                                    'consumer_secret' => $consumerSecret,
                                    'user_token'      => $oAuthToken,
                                    'user_secret'     => $oAuthSecret,
                                    'curl_timeout' => 60,
                                    'curl_ssl_verifypeer' => 0
                                  ));

    $code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/retweet/'),
            array('id' => '505041593686974464' ));

    echo  $code;
?>
```

How can I retweet in Twitter using the `tmhOAuth.php` class?

Note: I already created an app to post text and images to my Twitter using the `tmhOAuth.php` class.

Comment: I don't know if it is helpful, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20359452/2675154) explains something about error 410.

Comment: thanks I found my error (This resource is gone.) but do you have any idea how to retweet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes):

> This resource is gone. Used to indicate that an API endpoint has been
>   turned off. For example: “The Twitter REST API v1 will soon stop
>   functioning. Please migrate to API v1.1.”

Comment: thanks do you have any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try changing '1/statuses/retweet/' to '1.1/statuses/retweet/', and let me know how it went.

Comment: I faced 404 error which is (The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.)

Comment: I agree with you I found my error but unfortunately there is no way to do retweet , and I don't know which class should I use.